# Chat between me and chatbot does not appear in area meant for the chat to appear unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, chatbot

Hi so I'm trying to implement a AI chatbot into my unity game and I came across this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5267100/Integrating-a-Chatbot-into-Unity-in-Csharp I followed it step by step but whenever I type 'Hello Bot', it does not appear into the content area where it will show what I have typed to the bot and what the bot would reply to me and I have have no idea how to solve it.

PLease help here is the code

```
using Syn.Bot.Oscova;
using Syn.Bot.Oscova.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Message
{
    public string Text;
    public Text TextObject;
    public MessageType MessageType;
}

public enum MessageType
{
    User, Bot
}

public class BotDialog : Dialog
{
    [Expression("Hello Bot")]
    public void Hello(Context context, Result result)
    {
        result.SendResponse("Hello User!");
    }
}

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    OscovaBot MainBot;

    public GameObject chatPanel, textObject;
    public InputField chatBox;

    public Color UserColor, BotColor;

    List<Message> Messages = new List<Message>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            MainBot = new OscovaBot();
            OscovaBot.Logger.LogReceived += (s, o) =>
            {
                Debug.Log($"OscovaBot: {o.Log}");
            };

            MainBot.Dialogs.Add(new BotDialog());
            //MainBot.ImportWorkspace("Assets/bot-kb.west");
            MainBot.Trainer.StartTraining();

            MainBot.MainUser.ResponseReceived += (sender, evt) =>
            {
                AddMessage($"Bot: {evt.Response.Text}", MessageType.Bot);
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError(ex);
        }
    }

    public void AddMessage(string messageText, MessageType messageType)
    {
        if (Messages.Count >= 25)
        {
            //Remove when too much.
            Destroy(Messages[0].TextObject.gameObject);
            Messages.Remove(Messages[0]);
        }

        var newMessage = new Message { Text = messageText };

        var newText = Instantiate(textObject, chatPanel.transform);

        newMessage.TextObject = newText.GetComponent<Text>();
        newMessage.TextObject.text = messageText;
        newMessage.TextObject.color = messageType == MessageType.User ? UserColor : BotColor;

        Messages.Add(newMessage);
    }

    public void SendMessageToBot()
    {
        var userMessage = chatBox.text;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userMessage))
        {
            Debug.Log($"OscovaBot:[USER] {userMessage}");
            AddMessage($"User: {userMessage}", MessageType.User);
            var request = MainBot.MainUser.CreateRequest(userMessage);
            var evaluationResult = MainBot.Evaluate(request);
            evaluationResult.Invoke();

            chatBox.Select();
            chatBox.text = "";
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            SendMessageToBot();
        }
    }
}
```

Anything else yall need me to provide, I'll try to provide.

Thanks

Are there any suggestions to a better simple AI chatbots for a game like it acts as a helping hand or something. Thanks!

Comment: so  what exactly is not working? You mean when you type the text is shown but once you press `Return` then nothing happens? Have you tried [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) your code?

Comment: @derHugo yes it does not show the dialogue between myself and the bot in the dialogue box. I believe it has something to do with the AddMessage() function or for this version of unity it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed the alignment part in the screenshot. You can check in the logs window below if your code has any errors.

If the chat message is not visible then you might have not configured the components properly.

Below is the direct screenshot from the tutorial itself.

*Content Size Filter*

[image]

*Input Text*

[image]